# NSString - doubleValue is returning NaN from a viable NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Ok, so I am pulling an NSString from and NSMutableArray and storing it in an NSString:

```
entry = [NSString stringWithString:[array objectAtIndex:row]];
```

This is wrapped inside of a couple different for-loops. I then convert it to a doubleValue and store it in a number but apparently [entry doubleValue] only returns a NaN instead of a number.  I threw in an NSLog for 'entry' and '[entry doubleValue]'.  EVERY time I run this I get the same results:

```
entry: 22.414 value: nan
```

Any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're certain there aren't any other characters in the strings, have a look at the [`NSScanner`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class. It usually does a better job at reading strings.

Answer (score 3):

you might check to be sure that you don't have spaces or nonprinting characters in `entry`

Easiest way to do this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [entry dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yep, I'd say it's probably some non-printing characters. This works fine for me:

```
NSString *test = @"22.414";
NSLog(@"doubleValue: %f", [test doubleValue]);
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be, that you have set a system language where the locale says you are using for example comma instead of a dot as decimal seperator. I don't know if this happens with double value, but I had issues with NSNumberFormater.